# Firestore Security Rules for Query with Array Contains

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Flutter app in which users can make posts and tag the post as belonging to a group. Posts are stored in a global collection and each has a `Post.groupId` field:

```
/posts/{postId}
```

Based on my Firestore security rules and queries, users are only allow to read posts if they are in the group for which the post is tagged (i.e the posts's `groupId` field). Approved group users are stored in:

```
/groups/{groupId}/users/{userId}
```

I could query the posts from a particular user's group like:

```
_firestore.collection('posts').where('groupId', isEqualTo: 'groupA')...
```

This above was all working properly.

I am attempting to make an improvement in which a post can be tagged in multiple groups instead of just one, so I am replacing the single `Post.groupId` field with a `Post.groupIds` array. A user should be able to read a post if he/she is a member of ANY of the groups from `Post.groupIds`. I attempt to read all posts tagged with a particular group with the following query from my Flutter app:

```
_firestore.collection('posts').where('groupIds', arrayContains: 'groupA')...
```

I keep receiving the following exception `Missing or insufficient permissions` with these security rules:

```
match /posts/{postId} {
    allow read: if canActiveUserReadAnyGroupId(resource.data.groupIds);
}

function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
}

function getActiveUserId() {
    return request.auth.uid;
}

function isActiveUserGroupMember(groupId) {
    return isSignedIn() &&
            exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/users/$(getActiveUserId()));
}

function canActiveUserReadAnyGroupId(groupIds) {
    return groupIds != null && (
            (groupIds.size() >= 1 && isActiveUserGroupMember(groupIds[0])) ||
            (groupIds.size() >= 2 && isActiveUserGroupMember(groupIds[1])) ||
            (groupIds.size() >= 3 && isActiveUserGroupMember(groupIds[2])) ||
            (groupIds.size() >= 4 && isActiveUserGroupMember(groupIds[3])) ||
            (groupIds.size() >= 5 && isActiveUserGroupMember(groupIds[4]))
            );
}
```

With these security rules I can read a single post but I cannot make the above query. Is it possible to have security rules which allow me to make this query?

**UPDATE 1**

Added `isSignedIn()` and `getActiveUserId()` security rules functions for completeness.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the error I am receiving when I attempt to execute this query with the Firestore Emulator locally:

```
     FirebaseError: 
Function not found error: Name: [size]. for 'list' @ L215
```

Line 215 corresponds to the `allow read` line within this rule:

```
match /posts/{postId} {
    allow read: if canActiveUserReadAnyGroupId(resource.data.groupIds);
}
```

Comment: When you run the query it is only looking for documents where `groupIds` contains `groupA`, and then it is returning that document. There is no need to check the whole `groupIds` array since you are only looking for `groupA`. Therefore you only need to check `isSignedIn() && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/users/$(getActiveUserId()))`.

Comment: @Nathan, according to OP’s question, the way a user has access to a post is if they have access to any group. Checking all groups seems necessary

Comment: @DanFein my bad, you're right.

Comment: You might be going over firebase's maximum number of exists() and get() calls for single-document requests and query requests (which is only 10). Exceeding the limit results in a permission denied error.

Comment: Might want to look at this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#security_rule_limits

Comment: @Nathan I don't believe I am exceeding any query request limits. It was working before when I had a single groupId field and it still does not work when I have a groupIds array with a single element.

Comment: In the spirit of full disclosure, please edit the question to indicate what exactly are `isSignedIn()` and `getActiveUserId()`  Please omit no detail required to process these rules.

Comment: Also note that there is a rules emulator that will let you test rules locally, along with much more detailed messages to help you understand what happened.  https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added `isSignedIn()` and `getActiveUserId()` above. Sorry, didn't realize I missed those. I tried testing with the online Simulator but it didn't allow for `list` with `array-contains` queries, but I didn't know about the local emulator. I will try testing with that to see what additional error messages I receive. Thanks

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added the error I am receiving from the emulator. Still unable to determine why I am getting the error since there is the null check before checking `size()`.

Comment: `Constraint` is not a `List`, it has only operator `in` and method `hasAny` defined. I answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76558475/2462633

Answer (score 3):

It appears Firestore does not currently support security rules for this scenario at the moment (thanks for your help tracking this down Doug Stevenson). I have come up with a mechanism to work around the limitation and wanted to share in case someone else is dealing with this issue. It requires an extra query but keeps me from having to create a Web API using the Admin SDK just to get around the security rules.

Posts are stored as follows (simplified):

```
/posts/{postId}
- userId
- timestamp
- groupIds[]
- message
- photo
```

Now I am adding an additional post references collection which just stores pointer information:

```
/postRefs/{postId}
- userId
- timestamp
- groupIds[]
```

The `posts` collection will have security rules which does all the validation to ensure the user is in at least one of the groups in which the post is tagged. Firestore is able to handle this properly for simple `get` requests, just not `list` requests at the moment.

Since the `postRefs` collection stores only ID's, and not sensitive information which may be in the post, its security rules can be relaxed such that I only verify a user is logged in. So, the user will perform post queries on the `postRefs` collection to retrieve a list of ordered `postId`'s to be lazily loaded from the `posts` collection.

Clients add/delete posts to/from the normal `posts` collection and then there is a Cloud Function which copies the ID information over to the `postRefs` collection.

Comment: IMHO, an unfortunate workaround. Today is mid-2022. And there STILL is no way to validate an array value of a query constrain in a LIST type request. So simple stuff like ACLs - or GroupIDs in your case - is not possible where a user can have many groups and a document can be accessible to many groups.

Answer (score 3):

As per this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html), if you can maintain an index of member IDs for a given post (based on group assignments), then you can secure post read access storing member IDs in an array data type and matching against the member IDs with the "array-contains" clause in your ruleset. It looks like this in your Firebase rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
     allow read: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members
     allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, I'd say that groupIds isn't actually a List type object, which means that the field from the document is also not an array.  If it's a string, this code won't work, since strings don't have a method called `size()` in the rules language.

If you aren't 100% certain what the type of field is going to be, you will need to check the type in the rule and determine what to do with it.  You can use the `is` operator to check the type.  For example, `groupIds is list` will be boolean true if you're actually working with one.

In your rules, you can use the `debug()` function to dump the value of some expression to the log.  It will return the same value.  So, you can say `debug(groupIds) != null` to both print the value and check it for null.

Comment: I did verify `groupIds` is an array in the database document. However, I added the `debug(groupIds) != null` call to the rule and it prints the following. `constraint_value {
  simple_constraints {
    comparator: LIST_CONTAINS
    value {
      string_value: "groupA"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Hmm, actually, the way that rules work, it can't provide a value for each document evaluated individually (it's not going to read each possible document - that won't scale).   Instead, it's going to provide a description of what the query looks like so that the rules can check the validity of the query more generally.

Comment: Gotcha, then is there a way to extract the `string_value` out of the constraint so I verify user access to that group? I tried the following but it gives an error: `groupIds.constraint_value.simple_constraints.value.string_value`. Here is the error I now get: `Type error. Received: [constraint] Expected: [map,path]. for 'list' @ L219`

Comment: The value behaves kind of a like a list, but not totally.  What you can do here is check if something exists in the constraints given by the client.  You should be able to say `"groupA" in resource.data.groupId` to check what the client sent.  That's about as much as I know right now.  I'm told `resource.data.groupId[0]` will not.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot hardcode the group like `"groupA" in resource.data.groupIds"` in the security rules as the groups are user-generated. I also tried `resource.data.groupIds[0]` but got the following error: `Function not found error: Name: [[]]. for 'list' @ L219`

Comment: I understand.  I think what you're trying to do is currently not possible with security rules. At least not for queries.  Individual document gets should be OK, as you can access the entire list from the document being fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added a workaround I'm planning on implementing.