# Firestore Security Rules with advanced public/token rules and array-contains

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm working on an app with the following db:

```
organizations/{ordId}

organizationsPrivateData/{orgId}

events/{eventId}
```

an **organization** is composed of:

- owner: uid
- public: boolean

an **event**:

- title: string
- organizationId: string

an **organizationPrivateData**:

- organizationId: string (though the organizationPrivateData id is itself the organizationId)
- readToken: string

I've two case to manage:

#### CASE 1

The organization is "public" (true), thus all events are readable without any token. This is done with the following security rules `isOrganizationPublic`:

```
// DB Read
function organizationData(organizationId) { return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/$(organizationId)).data }
function organizationPrivateData(organizationId) { return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizationsPrivateData/$(organizationId)).data }

// Auth management
function authenticated() { return request.auth.uid != null }
function isAdmin(data) { return data.owner == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid in data.members}
function isEmailVerified() { return request.auth.token.email_verified == true }

// Tokens management
function isOrganizationReadAccepted (organizationId, readToken) {
    let organization =  organizationData(organizationId);

    return isOrganizationPublic(organization);
}

function isOrganizationPublic (organization) { return organization.public == true }
function isReadTokenValid (organizationId, token) { return organizationPrivateData(organizationId).readToken == token }

match /events/{eventId} {
    allow read: if isOrganizationReadAccepted(resource.data.organizationId, debug(resource.data.token));
}


match /organizations/{organizationId} {
    allow get: if isOrganizationReadAccepted(organizationId, request.resource.data.token);
}

match /organizationsPrivateData/{orgId} {
    allow read: if authenticated() && isAdmin(organizationData(resource.data.organizationId));
}
```

#### CASE 2

The `organization.public = false`. Then the `isOrganizationPublic` return false and we can do a ternary to do additional check. The goal there is to check for the `organizationPrivateData` to ensure the `readToken` is valid. My idea was to pass the token from the client through the where clause like so :

```
app
    .collection('events')
    .where('organizationId', "==", "org1")
    .where('token', 'array-contains-any', ["",'azerty'])
    .get()
```

Rules: `return isOrganizationPublic(organization) ? true : isReadTokenValid(organizationId, resource.data.token[0])`

**Problem**: I'm blocked here. If this could works, I need to have a "token" field on each event with an empty string which is ok on my side. Thus if the security is passed, the real "where" can return all granted events.

When doing additional check on the available where operator (in, array-contains, array-contains-any)  it seems that:

- `in`: the value within the rules is a string, probably called multiple times with each array value
- `array-contains`: is a different struct which looks like `constraint_value { simple_constraints { comparator: LIST_CONTAINS value { string_value: "" } } }`. Also getting only one value
- `array-contains-any`: looks like `array-contains` but has all the where array inside.

**Possible solution not optimal:** having the token inside each "event". This would work but uppon token renewal I'll need to change all event of this organization, which is not optimal and could take time too.

Not solution:

- using `hasAny` and 'in' operator, in does not have all the array value.
- extracting the first item of the array, `array-contains-any` is not an array.

Full source is available on [github here](https://github.com/HugoGresse/Ical2Api/pull/6/files#diff-83d58f9f0b80d1a91d471b4925803876)

Possible related questions: [Firestore Security Rules for Query with Array Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063931/firestore-security-rules-for-query-with-array-contains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a join between two collections in a way that is not possible in Firestore. As you mention it yourself, the only solution would be to have the `token` in each `event` document.

You could use this solution so you dont have to update all `event` documents on token renewal:

1. `organizationsPrivateData`: use an array `readTokens` holding all the historical tokens, append the new one on renewal
2. Change your rules to:

   ```
   function isReadTokenValid (organizationId, token) {
     return token in organizationPrivateData(organizationId).readTokens;
   }
   ```