# How to get the value of a Firestore security rules array-contains constraint for LIST type query?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am making a query like `db.collection('accounts').where('access.users', 'array-contains', [ user1.ref ])`

`user1.ref` is a `DocumentReference` to a document in the users collection that enables this user to read this account and its child collections, like an ACL

In the Firebase security rules emulator, if I debug the property `resource.data.access.users` I can see that is type `constraint_value`. And I can see the value for the array I passed:

```
constraint_value {
  simple_constraints {
    comparator: LIST_CONTAINS
    value {
      path_value {
        segments {
          simple: "databases"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "(default)"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "documents"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "users"
        }
        segments {
          simple: "account-1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how can I get the actual LIST value (in this case a LIST of of user references) of this `constraint_value` in the security rules so that I can check permissions using a LIST method like `hasOnly()` or `hasAll()`

There is no `value` property or `value()` method and in fact `constraint_value` isn't any type of interface in the docs ....

Comment: Could you please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063931/firestore-security-rules-for-query-with-array-contains) and see if it helps?

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB - yes, I did previously read this but whilst it does suggests work arounds to maintain another index - it doesn't discuss how (or if its possible) to extract and use the value of a array-oriented query value. In my case, such a work around isn't possible. I must be able to post an array of groups and check that the user has access to one or more of these groups. I suspect its not supported ...

Comment: This is currently not supported by Firestore Security Rules. I would suggest creating a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) for this case.

Comment: where you able to solve it? I've got the same requirement