# Firestore security rules based on constraint values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When using queries the resource variable points to the actual query being made.

How can we access the query arguments in firestore rules and apply restrictions based on the query arguments ?

in this specific case I want to know if the query uses a filter that begins with uid of the currently authenticated user.

the query I use is `where('tags', 'array-contains', ${context.user.id}_${context.month})`

and using `debug(resource.data.tags)` in firestore rules logs:

```
constraint_value {
  simple_constraints {
    comparator: LIST_CONTAINS
    value {
      string_value: "EqrtNecgmGWVdLOqOmacFRE6uDef_1659312000"
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

document structure is:

```
{
    creatorId: <uid>
    tags:['<uid>_<month>',....]
    data: .....
}
```

I can obtain the required behavior using this query:

```
.where('creatorId','==',<uid>).where('tags','array-contains',<uid>_<month>)
```

and this function to validate

```
function isDocCreator(){
    return request.auth.uid.matches(resource.data.creatorId)
}
```

however this will require an index to be created and the whole purpose of creating the `tags` attribute goes to waste

It would be nice to be able to access the constaint values by index and get rid of unnecessary index

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure, and code of your query?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the code with the query and explain what specifically you want the rule to allow or disallow.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase rules define data types. Some of them are well documented: `Map`, `List`, `Set`. Some of them are not: `Constraint`.
The good thing about open source code is that we can go and check the code to know for sure.

If you open firestore emulator .jar (in my case it was `cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.17.4.jar`), you will find all those types in the package `com.google.firebase.rules.runtime.impl.types`.

The one we are interested in (`ConstraintType`) has two methods:

- operator `in` (like `"someValue" in someConstraint`)
- method `hasAny()` (like `someConstraint.hasAny(["someValue1", "someValue2"])`)

Comment: I can confirm this works. I was concerned that this was an emulator-only feature, but it works in production too on the real firestore instance!

Answer (score 0):

The only property you can check from the query itself is its `limit` clause)

What you *can* do in the rules is say that the user has access to all documents where a field starts with a certain value:

```
allow read: if resource.data.field >= request.auth.uid
            && resource.data.field <= request.auth.uid  + '~';
```

If a user then creates a query on that same with field a condition, the rules can validate that they're not trying to get any documents they don't have access to, and the query is allowed.

But I'm not sure if there's a way to rewrite the above condition for array members as there are no operation to loop over an array/[list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) in the rules.

Comment: inside firestore rules in the list context resource.data points to the actual query. the expression `where('someField','==','someValue')` will result in `resource.data = {someFiled:'someValue'}` and we can use `resource.data.someField` to determine if the user has the ability to request for documents that have `someField == 'someValue'`. Unfortunately `where('someField','array-contains','someValue')` does not translata to `resource.data = {someFiled:'someValue'}`  even tho it is actually the same thing

Comment: `array-contains` in a query would translate to an `in` in the rules, but I don't think you can do anything like "where the array contains an item that matches this pattern". That would be a look, which don't exist in security rules for scalability reasons.

Comment: Stop looking at the data of the documents. 
Look at the query instead.
Is the user allowed to ask for a list that contains value X in field Y ??? 
Please read the comment above using this mindset.
Unfortunately not all query values can be access inside the rules script.
values for `where(<field>,'==',<value>)` can be accessed and values for `where(<field>,'array-contains',<value>)` can not,
even tho it is the same one to one relation so no iteration is involved.